# Suddenly home redirects to settings#/subscription

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-spark

A very annoying just surfaced. I did some database tweaking, migrated it and manually imported the user table together with some other tables.

Suddenly the home page of my laravel spark won't display properly. It automatically goes to the settings#/subscription page.

The routes are still intact but are the HomeController is not used at all. I've cleared all caches but still the same. No errors in the log.

And even more annoying as I just found out, it only affects existing users that I imported. New users are not affected. So it definitely has something to do with the MySQL import.

I already compared the users values of a new user and an old one and tried to mimick the new one as much as possible. Doesn't work.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while so you probably got to the bottom of this, but I just ran into the same issue.

In my case, I installed Spark without the team flag and signed up. Later, I added the necessary code to add teams back in without migrating and seeding. In a few places in my code I'm running the `teamSubscribed` middleware, and that was the crux of my problem. **The redirect started looking at the team subscription status instead of the user subscription status.**

Since I didn't sign up as a team, those fields were null, and it redirected pages with the middleware.

For others that come across this:

1. Search your codebase for the middleware (likely either in a constructor or your routes).
2. Double check your database for the corresponding user or team active trial status.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't touch anything with teams (although I might have done it by accident..) but probably your findings are probably useful for my problem as well. I don't even remember how I fixed it, probably started all over again...